# Changed hostname, closed before changing hosts, now sudo is broken, catch-22!

Tags: hostname

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04.

I was trying to change my computer name to "main" and I messed up, I'm not sure what to do now.

I was following the directions on [this page](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/windows-7-vs-ubuntu-12-04-how-to-change-your-computer-name/).

Here's what I did:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/hostname
```

I changed the name, then stupidly closed the file, *before* changing "/etc/hosts"

Now when I try to move on to the next step (sudo leafpad /etc/hosts), or try any command that begins with "sudo" I get this error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host main
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
```

I can see that the problem is that I've changed the hostname, so the computer's bewildered by my efforts to use sudo because now hostname and hosts don't match. All I need to do is change the name in hosts, but of course I can't do that without sudo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your hostname is in your /etc/hosts file

Comment: `/etc/hostname` has a single line for me: `vasa1-Inspiron-1545`. Also, when using a GUI-editor, use `gksudo` or `gksu`, not `sudo`.

Comment: And `/etc/hosts` has, among other things: `127.0.1.1 vasa1-Inspiron-1545`

Comment: What do you mean by "Now when I try to do anything"?

Comment: I just googled for `sudo: unable to resolve host main` and got a lot of hits. I'm going through them! BTW, as I commented earlier, don't use `sudo leafpad` but `gksudo leafpad` despite what that blogger wrote!

Comment: I definitely will in the future, but for now gksudo gives me this error: "leafpad: Cannot open display: No protocol specified"

Comment: Lekensteyn - Thanks so much. I don't know how to implement the solution in that question without the ability to use sudo, any ideas?

Comment: Boot into a LiveUSB, mount your partition, and edit `/etc/hosts`. If you don't know the steps, tell us what's the output of `mount | grep '/ '`

Comment: I appreciate your help, everyone. I tried this solution first and it worked beautifully:

You should be able to fix it from the recovery console, you will need to remount the filesystem with rw permissions and then use a commandline editor e.g. after dropping to the root shell,

Code:

# mount -o remount,rw /
# nano /etc/hosts

and make your changes... Ctrl-o to save and Ctrl-x to quit

Comment: Amc - Whoops, sorry about that. Done! (It says I can't accept my own answer for another 2 days, so I'll have to do that part later.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLVED:

You should be able to fix it from the recovery console, you will need to remount the filesystem with rw permissions and then use a commandline editor e.g. after dropping to the root shell,

Code:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
# nano /etc/hosts
```

and make your changes... Ctrl-o to save and Ctrl-x to quit