# unable to resolve host due to lost administrative password

Tags: hostname, administrator

I lost my admin password and changing it via root during start up does not make changes i'm guessing due to "unable to resolve host issue" and i can not change the host issue without the password. How do i go about it. 
I changed my host name via gui.

Comment: Cant really tell what the problem is from your post as admin password is unrelated to hostname. My guess is you have a problem with sudo and you have to have the proper hostname in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/319265/changed-hostname-closed-before-changing-hosts-now-sudo-is-broken-catch-22

Comment: The solution they have offered will not work for me as they require root privileges.. i lost my root password

Comment: You will have to use a live usb and fix it from there. You can also reset the root password from there if needed.